Expo React Native App Gradle assembleRelease Fails ( expo-modules-core:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED )
when i try to ./gradlew app:bundleRelease in android folder i get following error :
[androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1] C:\Users\PC\.gradle\caches\8.10.2\transforms\72f6facbb59ac7e98ce9b1e74d773807\transformed\versionedparcelable-1.1.1\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
        Namespace 'androidx.versionedparcelable' is used in multiple modules and/or libraries: androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1, com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0. Please ensure that all modules and libraries have a unique namespace. For more information, See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
C:\project\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:28:18-86 Error:
        Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.13.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:18-86
        is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:3-51:17 to override.

I looked up for solutions,  tried changing sdk versions but none of them worked at all
i figured out how to solve the issue but now i'm struggling with this :
> Task :expo-modules-core:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED
e: file:///C:/project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/AndroidExtensions.kt:10:59 Unresolved reference: TIRAMISU
e: file:///C:/project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/AndroidExtensions.kt:11:30 Too many arguments for public open fun <T : Parcelable!> getParcelableExtra(p0: String!): T? defined in android.content.Intent
e: file:///C:/project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/AndroidExtensions.kt:19:59 Unresolved reference: TIRAMISU
e: file:///C:/project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/AndroidExtensions.kt:20:25 Too many arguments for public open fun <T : Parcelable!> getParcelable(p0: String?): T? defined in android.os.Bundle
e: file:///C:/project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/AndroidExtensions.kt:28:59 Unresolved reference: TIRAMISU
e: file:///C:/project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/AndroidExtensions.kt:28:69 Type mismatch: inferred type is Serializable? but T? was expected
e: file:///C:/project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/AndroidExtensions.kt:29:27 Too many arguments for public open fun getSerializable(p0: String?): Serializable? defined in android.os.Bundle
-stacktrace :
> Task :expo-modules-core:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED
e: file:///C:/project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/AndroidExtensions.kt:10:59 Unresolved reference: TIRAMISU
e: file:///C:/project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/AndroidExtensions.kt:11:30 Too many arguments for public open fun <T : Parcelable!> getParcelableExtra(p0: String!): T? defined in android.content.Intent
e: file:///C:/project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/AndroidExtensions.kt:19:59 Unresolved reference: TIRAMISU
e: file:///C:/project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/AndroidExtensions.kt:20:25 Too many arguments for public open fun <T : Parcelable!> getParcelable(p0: String?): T? defined in android.os.Bundle
e: file:///C:/project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/AndroidExtensions.kt:28:59 Unresolved reference: TIRAMISU
e: file:///C:/project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/AndroidExtensions.kt:28:69 Type mismatch: inferred type is Serializable? but T? was expected
e: file:///C:/project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/AndroidExtensions.kt:29:27 Too many arguments for public open fun getSerializable(p0: String?): Serializable? defined in android.os.Bundle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:compileReleaseKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:compileReleaseKotlin'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:293)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:116)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:209)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)       
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:331)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.lambda$execute$0(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:85)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:459)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:376)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:287)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.lambda$waitForItemsAndGatherFailures$2(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:335)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:318)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLock(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:323)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:126)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForAll(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:78) 
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:252)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:229)  
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:212) 
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:195)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:162)        
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:105)        
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:209)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:42) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:75)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.PreCreateOutputParentsStep.execute(PreCreateOutputParentsStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.PreCreateOutputParentsStep.execute(PreCreateOutputParentsStep.java:28)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureOutputsAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureOutputsAfterExecutionStep.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureOutputsAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureOutputsAfterExecutionStep.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:189)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:75)  
        at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:53)       
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:35)       
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveIncrementalCachingStateStep.executeDelegate(ResolveIncrementalCachingStateStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveIncrementalCachingStateStep.executeDelegate(ResolveIncrementalCachingStateStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractResolveCachingStateStep.execute(AbstractResolveCachingStateStep.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractResolveCachingStateStep.execute(AbstractResolveCachingStateStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:65)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:36)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:107)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.java:125)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.HandleStaleOutputsStep.execute(HandleStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.HandleStaleOutputsStep.execute(HandleStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:289)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ChoosePipelineStep.execute(ChoosePipelineStep.java:40)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ChoosePipelineStep.execute(ChoosePipelineStep.java:23)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.lambda$execute$2(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:46)     
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:34)     
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:127)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:116)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:209)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)       
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:331)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.lambda$execute$0(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:85)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:459)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:376)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:48)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.CompilationErrorException: Compilation error. See log for more details
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwExceptionIfCompilationFailed(tasksUtils.kt:20)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.run(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:141)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction.execute(GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers.kt:73)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:209)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$0(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:194)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:127)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:263)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:127)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:132)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:133)
        ... 2 more

package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "2.1.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.10.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^7.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^7.0.0",
    "expo": "52.0.19",
    "expo-blur": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.13.1",
    "expo-camera": "~16.0.10",
    "expo-constants": "~17.0.3",
    "expo-font": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-haptics": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~16.0.3",
    "expo-linking": "~7.0.3",
    "expo-local-authentication": "~15.0.1",
    "expo-location": "~18.0.4",
    "expo-router": "~4.0.13",
    "expo-speech": "^13.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.29.18",
    "expo-status-bar": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-symbols": "~0.2.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~4.0.6",
    "expo-web-browser": "~14.0.1",
    "nativewind": "^4.1.23",
    "react": "19.0.0",
    "react-dom": "19.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.76.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.21.2",
    "react-native-maps": "1.20.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.16.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "5.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~4.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "15.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.13",
    "react-native-webview": "13.12.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.17"
  }

android>build.gradle
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.tarikcan.project'
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }

android>app>build.gradle
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '35.0.0'
        minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '24')
        compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '35')
        targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '34')
        kotlinVersion = '1.5.21'
// kotlinVersion = findProperty('android.kotlinVersion') ?: '1.9.24'
        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
    }

I also tried other kotlin and ndk versions, but none of them seems to be the solution. I installed expo-modules-core using npm but it didn't work as well. I guess there is a problem with this module.

Eventually i couldn't figure the problem out. I craeted an empty project with expo router and then coded all of the things again. This time it worked! I don't know what was the problem. But this time when i got the apk on my device there was a problem because of google maps api key, even if i provided in app config it couldn't see the api key, so i manually added the api key of mine to manifest.xml then the program didn't give any errors or crashes
